# how to get the userinfo of the authorized user in django oauth2_toolkit?

Tags: django, django-oauth-toolkit

Basically In oauth2 protocol after authentication, we get the access_token from the token endpoint using the code we got after successfull authentication.

My Concern is how to get the Userinfo.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had the same concern and dived into the source code and played around with the code, until I reached to this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66422779/9682023).

I still don't find it appealing to play around with the source code in this way, but it does do what I need.

If you have found any better solution, please share it here.